# Instant vs ZoneDateTime. Converting to another timezone

Tags: java, timezone, java-time, date-conversion, zoneddatetime

I'm having a hard time understanding java.time between **ZoneDateTime** - **Instant** - **LocalDateTime**
, so far, the only thing I know of is:

- Instant works in-between the two
- Instant (in my understanding), is a Stamp of time from the moment of time (UTC), a stamp of time that is relevant to the flow of human time, but without a time zone
- Zone Date time has TimeZone
- Instant does not have Time Zone but can deal with it given that a Zone information is supplied
- LocalDate time does not have time zone and cannot deal with zones, it's a Date Time without any relevance on the continuation of entire flow of time (global).

So I have this conversion below

```
val seoul = "Asia/Seoul"

val zoneId = ZoneId.of(seoul)
val now = ZonedDateTime.now()

val convertedZoneDateTIme = ZonedDateTime.of(now.toLocalDateTime(), zoneId).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
val convertedInstant = now.toInstant().atZone(zoneId)

// expected output
println(convertedInstant.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)))

// not expected output
println(converted.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)))
```

**Output**

```
2021-05-02 03:15:13
2021-05-02 09:15:13
```

I'm trying to convert a given time to another Time Zone, a use-case where a user moved to a different timezone and I need to update any information about a stored date.

Why am I getting an incorrect value on the second one..? Why do I have to convert it to Instant first and proceed with conversion?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your "convertedInstant" is NOT an instant but a `ZonedDateTime`. My recommendation: Use explicit types instead of `val`. And choose a format showing the time zone. Then you will see that first result is in UTC while second result is in South Korean zone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of your bullets are fully correct. Only you should not use `Instant` for working between `LocalDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` as you said in your first bullet. Converting between `Instant` and `LocalDateTime` requires a time zone (or at least an offset from UTC), so should go through a `ZonedDateTime`. So `ZonedDateTime` is the one to use between the two others. As I said, the rest is correct.

You are not being perfectly clear about what you had expected from your code nor how more specifically observed result differs. Assuming you wanted to use the same point in time throughout, this line is where your surprise arises:

```
val convertedZoneDateTIme = ZonedDateTime.of(now.toLocalDateTime(), zoneId).withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

`now` is a `ZonedDateTime` in your own time zone (the default time zone of your JVM to be precise). By taking only the date and time of day from it and combining them with a different time zone you are keeping the time of day but in that way (probably) changing the point in the flow of time. Next you are converting to UTC keeping the point in time (the instant), thereby (probably) changing the time of day and possibly the date. You have got nothing left from the `ZonedDateTime` that was your starting point, and I can’t see that the operation makes sense. To convert `now` to UTC keeping the point on the timeline use the simpler:

```
val convertedZoneDateTIme = now.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

With this change your two outputs agree about the point in time. Example output:

> ```
> 2021-05-07 02:30:16 +09:00 Korean Standard Time
> 2021-05-06 17:30:16 +00:00 Z
> ```

I used a `format` of `uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss xxx zzzz`.

Also for you other conversion I would prefer to use `withZoneSameInstant()`. Then we don’t need to go through an `Instant`.

```
val convertedInstant = now.withZoneSameInstant(zoneId)
```

It gives the same result as your code.

A short overview of what is in each of the classes discussed:

| Class | Date and time of day | Point in time | Time zone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `ZonedDateTime` | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| `Instant` | - | Yes | - |
| `LocalDateTime` | Yes | - | - |

Basically you don’t have any use for `LocalDateTime` for your purpose, and also `Instant`, while useable, isn’t necessary. `ZonedDateTime` alone fulfils your needs.

Comment: I haven't been back to my tests yet, but I really appreciate the effort on explaining it to me concisely. I'll take not that ZonedDateTime alone can solve my problem from switching from zone to another zone.